# Selenium Ignore SSL ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I appreciate this has been asked and answered many times and I have the ChromeDriver options code I need to add to resolve my problem, but I'm hoping someone can make sense of the code that I've adopted and help me work the options into it.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
```

This is in the WebBrowser Class which allows the tests to pick up any driver for a browser we tell it from a Config file

```
    public class WebBrowser : IWebBrowser, IDisposable
    {
        public WebBrowser(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.Driver = driver;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The web driver.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly IWebDriver Driver;

        /// <summary>
        /// Formats a script name for the browser type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string ScriptName(string filename)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = this.Driver;

            string result = String.Format("{0}_{1}.exe", filename,
                driver is InternetExplorerDriver ? "IE" :
                driver is ChromeDriver ? "Chrome" :
                driver is FirefoxDriver ? "FF" :
                null);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Scripts are not available for the current browser.");
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the web browser.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            if (WebBrowser.IsStarted) throw new InvalidOperationException(@"The browser has already been started.");

            WebBrowser._current = new WebBrowser(driver);
        }
```

And this is where I believe the whole test is started with Specflow

```
        public static void BeforeTestRun()
        {
            KillServers();
            KillBrowsers();

            Service.Instance.ValueRetrievers.Unregister(Service.Instance.ValueRetrievers.Single(p => p.GetType() == typeof(DateTimeValueRetriever)));
            //Service.Instance.RegisterValueRetriever(new RelativeDateTimeValueRetriever());


            HelperSettings.Configure(s =>
            {
                s.FindErrorCode = driver =>
                {
                    IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#errorCode"));
                    var code = (HttpStatusCode)int.Parse(elem.GetAttribute("value"));
                    return code;
                };
            });

            DependencyResolver.Start();

            WaitHelper = DependencyResolver.Find<IWaitHelper>();
            //FileHelper = DependencyResolver.Find<IFileHelper>();
            SignInHelper = DependencyResolver.Find<ISignInHelper>();

            Driver = DependencyResolver.Find<IWebDriver>();

            Global = new TransformGlobalContext();
            Feature = new TransformFeatureContext();
            Scenario = new TransformScenarioContext();

            var config = TestHelper.GetTestConfiguration();

            WebBrowser.Start(Driver);

            // Resize browser
            Driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size
            {
                Width = config.Browser.Width,
                Height = config.Browser.Height,
            };

            // Navigate to tenant
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(config.TenantUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in completely the wrong place for the creation of the instance for each browser driver.

```
   public static IWebDriver CreateInstance()
    {
        if (Driver != null)
        {
            return Driver;
        }

        var config = TestHelper.GetTestConfiguration();

        string path = config.DriverPath;
        string name = config.Browser.Name;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Browser not specified");
        }

        IWebDriver driver = Driver =
            name == "InternetExplorer" ? new InternetExplorerDriver(path) as IWebDriver :
            name == "Firefox" ? new FirefoxDriver() as IWebDriver :
            name == "Chrome" ? Chrome(path) :
            null;

        if (driver == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unsupported browser '{name}'");
        }

        return driver;
    }

    private static IWebDriver Chrome(string path)
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;

        return new ChromeDriver(path, options);
    }
```